# severe artifacts pixelation when using cuda rendering premiere pro

Tags: premiere, encoding, playback, rendering

In premiere pro when I set the renderer to GPU Acceleration (CUDA), for the timeline and on media encoder export, half the video is completely messed up with lots of pixelation artifacts when I switch on any effect or make a change in the lumetri colour panel. Any solutions?

I'm running premiere pro 2020 v14.3.0 and have the GTX 1060 3GB GPU with Nvidia drivers 451.48.
I have also tried reinstalling both and deleting all the cache to no effect.

[image: playback pixelation destroyed video]

Comment: Could you post your export settings please?

Comment: Hi this issue happens in the timeline window as well as the render export only when GPU rendering is on making me think it's independent of the export settings. I use h.264 full hd 1080p export preset.

Comment: Oh yikes - could it be that the footage is corrupted? What happens when you use a different clip in the timeline?

Answer (score 1):

Rolled back the Nvidia driver to the version before and it seems to have fixed it. Might be a bug. Typical!